# apache dev package installation in FreeBSD 11?

Tags: apache-2.4, freebsd, freebsd-ports

How do you install the dev package of apache24 in FreeBSD 11. It is not in the ports or in the package repositories or is it?

Comment: It's not in ports or packages so either it needs to be installed by downloading from Apache and configuring it yourself or it's under a different name, which I doubt but I haven't looked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download current/dev branch of the sources and build it yourself with

```
cd tempdir
fetch http://path.to.the/sourcepack.tar.bz2
tar zxf sourcepack.tar.bz2
cd httpd-x.x.x
./configure [--option ...]
make
make install
```

The essential part is to choose the proper set of options to build `httpd` that wouldn't conflict with the `httpd` from ports/packages. Read thoroughly the output of the `./configure -h` for all available options and their meaning.